# Nivo slider for Joomla not working on Chrome (jQuery based)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, joomla, nivo-slider

I am using a [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)-based Joomla 1.5 image slider module.

The slider works perfectly fine on FireFox and IE, as can be seen on [our website](http://www.openmindprojects.org/training/).

It used to work fine on Chrome, too but it doesn't anymore and I don't have a clue why.

The module is jQuery based for sure and I am using jQuery 1.6.3 for this one.

Comment: Because I am new I can only add two links per comment. So, here is the [module website](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/images-slideshow/18640) and [Joomla homepage](http://www.joomla.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You are loading jQuery twice, once with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.openmindprojects.org/iframe/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

and again

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Not to mention the fact you have `mootools.js` loading, this is a start to your conflicting problems.

Make sure that

1. You don't have any JavaScript errors. I spot 2.
2. You aren;t loading jquery twice, and if mootools is running, run jQuery in conflict mode
3. The order of your Javascript files are fine. i.e. you are loading a library before a call, not a call after a library.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://yourdomain.com/media/mod_vt_nivo_slider/js/jquery.nivo.slider.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon in SO, as they are not very helpful compared to answers that have some explanation about why your code solves the problem, and what you think the root cause is that this code solves.